# How to add an image to the radio button when its selected/checked to "true" with CSS

Tags: css, radio-button, checked

Is it possible to add an image to a radio button when it's selected/checked to `true` using **CSS** only ?

### For Example

I have three radio buttons and when I select any one of them I want to add an image with a check icon

I know it can be done with JavaScript and jQuery, but I want to know if this can be done with CSS only, I have tried doing it different ways with **CSS** but didn't work.

Comment: Google search checkbox generator and you might get what u want :)

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi Thank You! got it what I want

Comment: As you've shown none of your code it's hard for us to really offer anything practical beyond generic suggestions or guesses; you say you've solved the problem - which is great! - but to improve the quality of the question, and to make it useful for future visitors, could you add the "*[mcve]*" code you're working with, show one of your attempted (failing) solutions and explain why/how it didn't work? Then, also, post your answer below.